# Cannot locate file:tmp/cassandra.yaml?

Tags: windows, maven, cassandra

While running the Usergrid server which makes use of cassandra in Windows, I'm coming across the following error and while it works fine in linux. Its a maven project and all dependencies are downloaded automatically. But this error is preventing the server from starting. Any solutions?

This is the Super POM of the project.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <bundle.symbolicName>org.usergrid</bundle.symbolicName>
        <bundle.namespace>org.usergrid</bundle.namespace>
        <cassandra-javautils-version>0.7.1</cassandra-javautils-version>
        <cassandra-version>1.0.6</cassandra-version>
        <hector-om-version>2.0-01</hector-om-version>
        <hector-version>1.0-3</hector-version>
        <hector-test-version>1.0-3</hector-test-version>
        <jackson-version>1.9.9</jackson-version>
        <jersey-version>1.11</jersey-version>
        <shiro-version>1.2.0</shiro-version>
        <junit-version>4.8.2</junit-version>
        <log4j-version>1.2.16</log4j-version>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <slf4j-version>1.6.1</slf4j-version>
        <snakeyaml-version>1.8</snakeyaml-version>
        <usergrid-custom-spring-properties>classpath:/usergrid-custom.properties</usergrid-custom-spring-properties>
        <usergrid-custom-spring-test-properties>classpath:/usergrid-custom-test.properties</usergrid-custom-spring-test-properties>
                <metrics-version>2.1.2</metrics-version>
    </properties>
    <groupId>org.usergrid</groupId>
    <artifactId>usergrid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>${bundle.symbolicName} [${bundle.namespace}]</name>
    <description>Usergrid Project</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>config</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>services</module>
        <module>tools</module>
        <module>mongo-emulator</module>
        <module>websocket</module>
        <module>rest</module>
        <module>standalone</module>
        <module>launcher</module>
        <module>count-common</module>
        <module>count-batcher</module>
        <module>count-inserter</module>
    </modules>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.3</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.datastax.hector</groupId>
                <artifactId>hector-composite</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.0-rc1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
                <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
                <artifactId>grizzly-http-servlet-server</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs.jersey-oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>oauth-signature</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs.jersey-oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>oauth-server</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.mock-javamail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mock-javamail</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.saxon</artifactId>
                <version>9.1.0.8_2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>r09</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.undercouch</groupId>
                <artifactId>bson4jackson</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.beoui</groupId>
                <artifactId>geocell</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javaee</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
                <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hector-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
                <artifactId>hector-test</artifactId>
                <version>${hector-test-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
                <artifactId>hector-object-mapper</artifactId>
                <version>${hector-om-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.0</version>
                <optional>false</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.0</version>
                <optional>false</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.0</version>
                <optional>false</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.amber</groupId>
                <artifactId>oauth2-common</artifactId>
                <version>0.2-ug-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.amber</groupId>
                <artifactId>oauth2-authzserver</artifactId>
                <version>0.2-ug-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.amber</groupId>
                <artifactId>oauth2-resourceserver</artifactId>
                <version>0.2-ug-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
                <version>${cassandra-version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-javautils</artifactId>
                <version>${cassandra-javautils-version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
                <version>${shiro-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
                <version>${shiro-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${shiro-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.29</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
                <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-smile</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.Final</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.python</groupId>
                <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scale7</groupId>
                <artifactId>scale7-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scale7</groupId>
                <artifactId>scale7-cages</artifactId>
                <version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>${snakeyaml-version}</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>${metrics-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${metrics-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${metrics-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Jenkins by default defines a property BUILD_NUMBER which is used to 
            enable the profile. -->
        <profile>
            <id>jenkins</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.BUILD_NUMBER</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.5.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <formats>
                                    <format>xml</format>
                                    <format>html</format>
                                </formats>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>package</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>usergrid-dependencies-snapshots</id>
            <name>Usergrid s3 dependencies snapshots repository</name>
            <url>https://usergrid-maven.s3.amazonaws.com/dependencies-snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>usergrid-dependencies</id>
            <name>Usergrid s3 dependencies repository</name>
            <url>https://usergrid-maven.s3.amazonaws.com/dependencies</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository-hector-dev.forge.cloudbees.com</id>
            <name>Hector Dev Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repository-hector-dev.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <name>codehaus</name>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>javageomodel-repo</id>
            <name>GeocellJava Repository</name>
            <url>http://javageomodel.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so (correct me if I'm wrong) I see that you don't bundle the app on the (dev or Continuous Integration) machine, then deploy it to your servers.

Instead, the server downloads all the files it needs.

So I would advise 3 things :

1) Find where, on the linux server, is located the cassandra.yaml file. tmp/cassandra.yaml might be a relative path, but relative to what ? When you locate it, you can trace how you got it, (from a jar ?), and we can advise.

2) I assume you had to install maven on both servers (windows and linux) as maven downloads the dependencies on each server.
Maybe something is different, or went wrong.

For instance, you could have a different maven setup (repositories), even if your pom seems to be self sufficient about repositories.
Or something could have been wrong the first time you downloaded a dependency. You can go in the windows server .m2 folder, and see if something is wrong with the cassandra dependencies (sometimes, you have to delete a broken "dependency", if it could not be downloaded the first time you tried).

3) I see some dependencies are accessed via https. You can try to see if this is not a problem, from your windows server.

Comment: I've edited my answer, with some steps you can follow to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Thanks for your time! will check one of them is the problem, btw I've been able to successfully start it on windows 7, this issue occurs in windows Xp.